# Resize iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to adapt the size of iframes on a site using javascript so that the iframes are as long as the content inside. My code is the following:

```
var iFrames = $('iframe');

function iResize() {        
    for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
        iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }
}

console.log( 'resize frame before' );
if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
    console.log( 'if' );            
    iFrames.load(function(){
        setTimeout(iResize, 0);
    });

    for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
        var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
        iFrames[i].src = '';
        iFrames[i].src = iSource;
    }               
} else {
    console.log( 'else' );
    $( '.iframe' ).load(function() { 
        console.log( 'load' );
        this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    });
}
console.log( 'resize frame end' );
```

It's not working but with the console.log the only log not appearing is inside the 'load' function.

I'm calling all the javascript at the bottom of the page, I'm not sure if that's causing the problem or not.

Any help would be much appreaciated.

---

Edit: source code is at https://github.com/xonorageous/projet-sas
Site can be viewed at http://daniel-lucas.com/experiments-dir/projet-sas/

Comment: Is the `iframe`'s source on the same domain? Don't forget about the Same-Domain Policy.

Comment: yes, the code for my iframe is <iframe src="sas/html/aston_martin_avg_year.htm" class="iframe" width="800"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this a lot easier in jQuery:

```
$(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() { 
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }

        });
```

See here for original source > http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/

Comment: Thank you BenM, this is the code I started with originally, in the code above I've just added some console.log

Comment: Thank you BenM, this is the code I started with originally, in the code above I've just added some console.log. For some reason the code just stops working when it enters iFrames.load

Comment: Which browser are you testing? You don't have a `console.log` statement inside Safari or Opera check...

Comment: I'm using chrome, I've already tried doing the log in the other check to see if it worked elsewhere

Comment: not at the moment, sorry, all the work is local. I can upload it if you want

Comment: Please do upload, this will make debugging somewhat easier.

Comment: I've uploaded the site to http://daniel-lucas.com/experiments-dir/projet-sas/ . The page I've been experimenting on is http://daniel-lucas.com/experiments-dir/projet-sas/index.php?page=marque&marque=aston-martin . The view for the page is in views/aston-martin.php . The javascript is in assets/js/main.js and the <script> tags are in views/layouts/layout.php at the bottom of the file. To access the code you can go to https://github.com/xonorageous/projet-sas/

Comment: On the Aston Martin page? All the other iframes have fixed heights at the moment

Comment: Thank you for your time and help BenM. It's working now, I suppose that it's the cache on my computer that was stopping the latest changes from showing.

Comment: Glad that you got it sorted, @xonorageous. Nice avatar, by the way ;)